# How should a dataset looks like for Time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, regression, prediction, forecasting, arima

What should a dataset look like for time series forecasting?

Can I do time series forecasting with a dataset that contains apartments from ad sites obtained with:

- web scraping from 2018 to 2021
- 13 features
- Date, Region, area, rooms, level, price, levels, type etc.

This the dataset link for further information about dataset [dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mrdaniilak/russia-real-estate-20182021/code)

Or should I have the historic of the change of price of these apartments over time?

Like an appartement in region 1 with 1 room costs X in 2018 and costs Y in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

What you described is a longitudinal panel dataset rather than timeseries data. As such you use methods for panel data regression, mostly fixed- or random effects. Good resources [here](https://theeffectbook.net/) and [here](https://mixtape.scunning.com/).

Comment: I don't understand your answer neither the ressources that You posted in your answer, should i convert m'y dataset to do future forecasting ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Timeseries datasets should first be representative enough of the business process they are dealing with.

For instance, some processes are better represented day by day, others, hours by hours, etc.

That's why you should first know the objective that will define the neccessary frequency and features, you cannot take all features and time values and get a good result: you should define at least one objective first, analyse your data, define which features seems meaningful, apply correlations functions to know the links between features, etc.

Once you have a good understanding of your dataset, you can start with a few features to see if your model work.

In your case, the best is to apply both solutions separately:

- Times series to detect how the market is changing and predict prices according to a few time-based features.
- Multi-dimensional prediction on most recent data in order to predict prices (or other things) using different features.

But you cannot have both solutions at the same time for a beginning. It is better to dissociate them using a few representative features, in order to get good results, and then increase complexity by crossing many feautures.

Comment: But there solutions like multivariate time series, arima and fbprophet with regressors , to predict prices not only according to time but there other characteristics to adjust the price prediction, my solution is to firstly convert my dataset to time series dataset and after that apply multivariate time series forecast, we can at the same time detect how price changes over time according to other features

Comment: Could you give an example of raw data you have editing your initial question? Converting data to time series is only possible assigning features to their date, hour, etc. If they are available, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: dataset has 13 fields.
  
date - date of publication of the announcement;
time - the time when the ad was published
region - Region
building_type - Facade type. 0 - Other. 1 - Panel. 2 - Monolithic. 3 - Brick. 4 - Blocky. 5 - Wooden
object_type - Apartment type. 1 - Secondary real estate market; 2 - New building;
level - Apartment floor
levels - Number of storeys
rooms - the number of living rooms
area - the total area of ​​the apartment
kitchen_area - Kitchen area
price - Price. in rubles

Comment: This is the link of the dataset on kaggle [dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mrdaniilak/russia-real-estate-20182021/code)

Comment: You have the date of publication, consequently you can apply a time series logic on some features like the market evolution on houses with 5 rooms. But you what is your objective? The features you select  depends on it.

Comment: My objective is to convert my dataset to be more correct for time séries analysis if needed , it will be correct if i calculate the mean of everything in every month and then apply fbprophet with regressors or calculate the average price per meter of every région for every month and remove price column and then apply fbprophet with regressors ,  ? or another approach is to create categories for my dataset like 1 room panel house situated between levels 0 and 3 in région 82 and calculate the historic of this category in every month and then apply fbprophet with regressors

Comment: My problem is that i can't understand how to convert my dataset to a time series dataset because maybe I'm wrong please correct if so , a time series it's like we have a product and we have the historic of price for this product maybe with other characteristics but it's the same product and so we can apply time series but here i have appartements that depend on other characteristics, the price is over time but it depends on other features ,  if for example i apply fbprophet with regressors on my dataset without changing anything will that be correct ?

Comment: That's why I'm asking if i can with my dataset apply Time séries analysis , i didn't find examples on internet and if so I think that their dataset is already adopted for this type of problem , maybe I'm not well understanding time series , but it's like confusing for me , what is the difference between a dataset that we can do linear regression with it and multivariate time series

Comment: If do you have for example this dataset that i shared the link and you need to do a forecasting, we will need to do multivariate time series I think , but what are the steps to do , like which changes should you perform on your dataset ? Or no changes are needed ?

Comment: My objective is to apply time series forecasting with features like rooms , level and levels and region this my objective not only time

Comment: You can just pick a notebook and apply your data on it, for instance: https://www.kaggle.com/code/tatianakovalenko/lab-5-timeseries

Comment: You can't have the perfect model at first shot, you have to investigate simple solutions first, and then increase in complexity.